# Markdown on vim - weird return/enter behavior on lists (gVim)

Tags: vim, markdown

When I insert an asterisk `(*)` for markdown list and then begin a new line `Enter\return`, the editor inserts a space in the next item (no other characters inserted). How can I repair this behavior?
[image: The issue as seen in the picture, without manual correction]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem on my Vim, even after starting vim with `vim -u NONE`. Can you try starting Vim that way, opening a markdown file, and seeing if the issue persists? If it does, that'll rule out a wonky `.vimrc`.

Comment: Is it possible you're referring to pasting in indented code? That can indeed cause this sort of issue.

Comment: Nope, it even happens on vim on linux' terminal. I'm forsaking this quest for now.